# Ionic >=2 Windows platform build always trying to use Any CPU

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp, ionic3

I have an Ionic application where I have just added the Window platform on a Windows PC that has only Visual Studio 2017 installed.

After some other initial problems, I think I am up to the last hurdle, and that is I am getting the following error when trying to build  (ie running ionic cordova build windows)...

```
Building project: H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
    Configuration : debug
    Platform      : anycpu
    Patching 10 in prebuild event...
    Injected base.js reference to the /www/index.html
    Removing /(
    *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from
    /www/index.html
    Removing /(
    *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/
    from /www/index.html
    Creating library
    H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\debug\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.lib
    and object
    H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\debug\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.exp
    SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj ->
    H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\debug\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.dll
    SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj ->
    H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\debug\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.pdb
    (Partial PDB)
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
    Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\Microsoft.Cpp.VCLibs120Universal.targets(103,5):
    warning MSB3842: Project "CordovaApp.Windows10" depends upon SDK "Microsoft Universal CRT Debug Runtime
    v10.0.15063.0" which supports apps targeting "UAP 10.0". To verify whether "Microsoft Universal CRT Debug
    Runtime v10.0.15063.0" is compatible with "UAP 10.0.15063.0", contact the SDK author or see
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181.
    [H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
    Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\Microsoft.Cpp.VCLibs120Universal.targets(103,5):
    error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the
    referenced SDK "Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug, Version=10.0.15063.0". Please consider changing the targeted
    processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to
    one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM, ARM64".
    [H:\dev\apps\mobileapps\myapp\trunk\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
    Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe: Command
    failed with exit code 1
```

The solution and project did originally have "Any CPU" set, but I have gone in and tried setting it to both x86 and ARM..

[image]

I have saved all, and I can build the solution in Visual studio, but when I do the ionic build, it is always complaining about the "any cpu".

Does anyone have any ideas why this is and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What command do you use to build the project?

If you just use `ionic cordova build windows` you should add the arch flag:

```
ionic cordova build windows -- --arch="x64"
```

Comment: thankyou for that, it works. What a weird flag, you need the "empty" `--` before the `--arch=x64` for it to work. How strange.